# IF/ELSE script in sender profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to create a dynamic sender profile where the from name and from email change if a value is present in a specific field of the data extension. I want the Lead First Name value and Lead Last Name values to appear. I'm trying to keep all the logic in the sender profile.

```ampscript
%%=IIF(EMPTY(AttributeValue("X")), "Bill", AttributeValue("LeadFirstName") AttributeValue("LeadLastName"))=%%
```

Not sure why, but doing the test, the script shows up as the sender and isn't resolving.

Comment: The above is missing an =

Comment: Thank you, it works with 1 value, but I want to pull in two values. So, if field is empty, show value 1 and value 2

Comment: Try using concat

Comment: Do you know how I could concat two attributes?

Comment: @mary - yes, using the [Concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's a typo in your question, but you forgot "=" when opening your Ampscript:

```ampscript
%%=IIF(EMPTY(AttributeValue("X")), "Bill", AttributeValue("LeadFirstName"))=%%
```